# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax: What is wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, subquery

Please have a look at the below query.

```
SELECT sub_words.idwords, words_inc.idArticle
(
    SELECT sub0.idwords, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords), ',', 10) AS excl_words,        COUNT(sub1.idwords) AS older_words_cnt
    FROM words_learned sub0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN words_learned sub1
    ON sub0.userId = sub1.userId
    AND sub0.order < sub1.order
    WHERE sub0.userId = 1
    GROUP BY sub0.idwords
) sub_words
INNER JOIN words words_inc
ON sub_words.idwords = words_inc.idwords
LEFT OUTER JOIN words words_exc
ON words_inc.idArticle = words_exc.idArticle
AND FIND_IN_SET(words_exc.idwords, sub_words.excl_words)
WHERE words_exc.idwords IS NULL
ORDER BY older_words_cnt
LIMIT 100
```

This gives the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT sub0.idwords, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sub1.idwords), ',', 10) AS exc' at line 3

I checked the sub query individually and there was no error in the sub query! what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `from` keyword

```
SELECT sub_words.idwords, words_inc.idArticle
FROM
( ...
```